# YUI3: How to bundle dependencies for offline deployment?

Tags: deployment, bundle, offline, dependency-management, yui3

I am building a web application using YUI3 and with it it's "Loader" and "App" components. I separate my application into different modules with YUI.add(). All is going well so far.

However, the application is going to be run off-line (distributed as a .zip file or so), with no access to the YUI CDN. I am looking for a way to neatly bundle all my dependencies without shipping the many megabytes that is YUI3.

Is there a best-practice way to bundle only the dependencies I need for my application?

The closest thing I found to this is http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yui/loader-resolve.html , but I feel there must be a easier way than to write something myself. I am willing to restructure my sources should I need to, or switch to using Builder or Shifter if that helps.